# Let $G,*$ a group and $a,b,c,d \in G$. Prove that ...

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $\langle G,*\rangle$ be a group and $a,b,c \in G$. Prove that the equation $x*a*x*b=x*c$ it has a unique solution in $G$.

Ideas? I do not know where to start.

Comment: Does $x$ have an inverse in $G$? And do you mean $d$ satisfies the equation in which you've put $x$?

Comment: where does $d$ go?

Comment: It was a mistake.

Comment: It seems your last equation was cut off.  What is $D$ equal to?

Comment: It was a typo, thanks for watching! ^^

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest way to prove that is to find the solution. The crutial thing is that any element of a group has an inverse.

$$xaxb=xc$$
Multiply by $x^{-1}$ on the left:
$$x^{-1}xaxb=x^{-1}xc$$
Since $x^{-1}x = e$ (where $e$ is the group neutral element):
$$axb=c$$
Multiply by $a^{-1}$ on the left and by $b^{-1}$ on the right:
$$x=a^{-1}cb^{-1}$$
So, $x$ is uniquely determined from the initial equation.

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{align}
xaxb=xc & \implies x^{-1}xaxb=x^{-1}xc\\
& \implies axb=c\\
& \implies a^{-1}axbb^{-1}=a^{-1}cb^{-1}\\
& \implies x=a^{-1}cb^{-1}.
\end{align}$$